# How to Make a GET Request from a Servlet

Tags: java, rest, servlets

I am trying to make a GET request to a certain URL and get some data that I am going to use inside a Java servlet. This is the code I am using:

```
 final HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder()
                .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_2)
                .build();

        String httpPath = "http://path/to/the/thirdparty/service";

        HttpRequest httpRequest = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .GET()
                .uri(URI.create(httpPath))
                .build();

        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

        try {
            httpResponse = httpClient.send(httpRequest, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            response.getWriter().println(e.getMessage());
        }



    response.setContentType("application/json");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println(httpResponse.body().toString());
```

This works perfectly and gives the desired output when I run the code from inside a standalone class inside it's main method. However, when I run this from the servelet, I can't produce the output. The response code is 200, however the content is missing with a curl error:

```
* transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
* Closing connection 0
curl: (18) transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
```

To see whether the length of the data is the problem, I hardcoded the output that is expected from the third party response (and commented out the call from httpClient), that gets sent out in the response correctly when I make a curl request to the servlet. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Which `HttpClient` implementation are you using? Is it some sort of `curl` wrapper?  Or are you using the native implementation in Java 11 and later?

Comment: I am using Java 11 native implementation

Comment: Are you trying to redirect a servlet to another servlet's doGet method?